# Jquery trigger key.Code event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

how to trigger  keyboard specif `key.Code` event with jQuery?

I woul like to trigger specifically backspace keyboard event

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 8; // some value (backspace = 8)
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onkeydown="return inspectKeyCode(event);">

function inspectKeyCode(event)
{
  if(event.keyCode == 8){
     //Do whatever

     //For disabling  return false;

  }
}
```

By this you can cancel the backspace button.

Comment: For disabling the default behavior use e.preventDefault(). This way you'll be able to safely add other keydown events, I.E. for testing.